# Json parsing in iOS playground do method is not parsing

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode7, swift-playground

I am trying to parse some json data into three different arrays based off the label in the json. I seem to be stuck and don't know why my for loop is never being entered. I am new to iOS and am using this to learn swift. Any help will be appreciated. 
Here is the code that I am using:

```
var myPicture = [String]()
var myPath = [String]()
var mylabel = [String]()


let jsonString = "[{\"picture\" : \"Picture 1 \", \"path\": \"Path 1\" , \"label\" : \"Label 1\"}]"
//Convert jsonString to NSData
let myData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!

do{

let promoJson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData, options:.AllowFragments)

if let promtions = promoJson[""] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

    for promtions in promtions {

        if let picture = promtions["picture"] as? String
        {
            myPicture.append(picture)

            if let path = promtions["path"] as? String
            {
                myPath.append(path)

                if let label = promtions["label"] as? String
                {
                    mylabel.append(label)

                }

            }
        }
    }

}

}catch {
print("Error with Json: \(error)")
}
print(myPicture.first)
print(myPath.first)
print(mylabel.first)
```

The results for the print are all nil. So nothing is being appended to the arrays

Comment: I don't know what the promtions = promoJson[""]... line is intending to be doing. Even if it does succeed, then  "for promtions in promotions"  is defiantly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if let promtions = promoJson[""]` part won't work and would be useless anyway. This is only `promoJson` that you have to cast to an array of dictionaries.

You weren't that far from the solution, look at my working version of your code:

```
do {
    let promoJson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData, options: [])
    if let promtions = promoJson as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        for promtion in promtions {
            if let picture = promtion["picture"] as? String {
                myPicture.append(picture)
            }
            if let path = promtion["path"] as? String {
                myPath.append(path)
            }
            if let label = promtion["label"] as? String {
                mylabel.append(label)
            }
        }
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.debugDescription)
}
```

---

*Alternative*

Now that the issue is resolved, let me suggest you another way: instead of separate arrays for your data, use one array of objects holding your data.

For example, make a struct like this:

```
struct Promotion {
    let picture: String
    let path: String
    let label: String
}
```

And an array for instances of this struct:

```
var myPromotions = [Promotion]()
```

Now we can decode the JSON, create objects from it then store them in the array:

```
do {
    let promoJson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData, options: [])
    if let promtions = promoJson as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        for promtion in promtions {
            if let picture = promtion["picture"] as? String,
                    path = promtion["path"] as? String,
                    label = promtion["label"] as? String {
                let promo = Promotion(picture: picture, path: path, label: label)
                myPromotions.append(promo)
            }
        }
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.debugDescription)
}
```

Now look at the content of the array, very convenient:

```
for promo in myPromotions {
    print(promo.label)
    print(promo.path)
    print(promo.picture)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are converting it is already an array.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var myPicture = [String]()
var myPath = [String]()
var mylabel = [String]()


let jsonString = "[{\"picture\" : \"Picture 1 \", \"path\": \"Path 1\" , \"label\" : \"Label 1\"}]"
//Convert jsonString to NSData
let myData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!

do{

    let promoJson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData, options:.AllowFragments) as! NSArray

        for promtions in promoJson {

            if let picture = promtions["picture"] as? String
            {
                myPicture.append(picture)

                if let path = promtions["path"] as? String
                {
                    myPath.append(path)

                    if let label = promtions["label"] as? String
                    {
                        mylabel.append(label)

                    }

                }
            }

    }

}catch
{
    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
}

print(myPicture.first) // "Optional("Picture 1 ")\n"
print(myPath.first) // "Optional("Path 1")\n"
print(mylabel.first) // "Optional("Label 1")\n"
```

This does the job.